Whether there is any need to modify the backward function in pytorch?
Recently I have been working on self-defined models with self-defined backward function (since the forward process is not implemented via pytorch AD). Say if I have a model of which the forward function outputs two tensors A and B. The backward function defines the gradients (dA/dP and dB/dP) of parameter P and the gradients of the whole loss will be composed of dA/dP and dB/dP.
Now I want to define a new differentiable function, which is f(A, B) = A * g(B) (multiply, not convolution), therefore the gradient of f(A, B) will be (dA/dP) * g(B) + A * g'(B) * (dB/dP).
So I figure, since dA/dP and dB/dP are already defined, f(A, B) should be directly differentiable, and there is no need to modify the backward function. My question is that since I am not sure about the above, I wonder whether this is correct and whether I need to modify the backward function (and the forward function, even).

Your notations are unclear, "the gradient of f(A, B)" wrt to what? Also, what is g' here? If the function you have here f is implemented with built-in functions that are differentiable, then I see no problem with what you have written. You don't need to write the derivate as u'v + uv', the derivative is computed with a chain function. And the multiplication operator will have its own derivative.

"the gradient of f(A, B)"  wrt to parameters P and the g here is a torch built-in differentiable operator (for example cos, exp). So in this case I just need to rely on AD and everything should work?

What do you mean by the forward process is not implemented via pytorch AD? Is the forward method not using pytorch? Can you post an example of these functions f and g?

@Karl forward function is implemented by CUDA. So I have to track the gradient myself.

In that case yes you also need to implement your own backward function

As long as you use differentiable built-in operators, Autograd will track your operations, and a backward call will result in gradient computation.
In your case, you have the following two operations:
C = g(B)
Z = A*C

So we can summarize the computation graph with:
dL/dB <------\    
  B   -----\  \ 
            \ dC/dB 
             \  \ <--- dL/dC ----\
              -> g(B) = C  ----\  \
                                \ dZ/dC
                                 \  \ <--- dL/dZ ---
                                  -> A * C = Z
                                 /  /
                                / dZ/dA
  A   -------------------------/  /
dL/dA <--------------------------/

Your input gradients A.grad and B.grad correspond to dL/dB and dL/dA, respectively. While, your model gradient will be given by dL/dC which is actually dL/dg (by g, we refer to the parameters for the "g" model). This quantity will be computed with the chain rule as dL/dC = dL/dz * dZ/dC.
You can read more in another question: Understanding backpropagation in PyTorch.

Thanks for answering. So… does this include situations where forward and backward functions are implemented manually (for example, CUDA C++)?

I mean, as I wrote in the post, A and B are obtained via CUDA C++ implementation, in this case, if g is a torch built-in differentiable operator, I can still use AD? Since I think in the post the gradient of f wrt to parameters P can be easily calculated (all components are known or the computation is defined).

"as I wrote in the post, A and B are obtained via CUDA C++ implementation", no this was not specified in your post. Since A and B are used as input, you don't need their gradient to update g, was that your question?

Yes, my question is, if A and B are not obtained with operators with AD and g is a built-in differentiable operator (no parameter to update), whether AD can be relied on if dA/dP and dB/dP are already given in self-defined backward function.

Depends if A and B are obtained with parameters P, are they? Is your model g, or there is more?

Yes, A and B can be considered as the output of some differentiable function with input P, yet the function can not be written with AD. g has nothing to do with P, it is a simple operator (for example, torch cos or exp).

Ok, so no you will have to implement a backward implementation for the function that produced A and B from P. Otherwise, there won't be any way for the gradient to pass from the output and loss to the input producing those tensors. I hope this clarifies any doubts you have.

Thanks! One last question is the do you think implementing the backward function will be simpler since (how to compute) dA/dP and dB/dP are known? As I wrote in the post (dA/dP) * g(B) + A * g'(B) * (dB/dP) is composed of known or 'easy-to-compute' parts, I think this will be far more straightforward than implementing it from scratch.

You should implement the derivatives of your operator only, which are dA/dP and dB/dP. Since the final derivative you are looking for is dL/dP which is dL/dA*dA/dP + dL/dB*dB/dP, via the chain rule. Thanks to Autograd, dL/dA and dL/dB will be already computed for you.
